# Prove that $f_{xy}(a, b)=f_{yx}(a, b)$

Tags: calculus, proof-writing

If I have a rational function $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$, how can I prove that $f_{xy}(a, b)=f_{yx}(a, b) \forall (a, b) \in D(f)$? Where $D(f)$ is the domain. From what I know, this is very similar to Clairaut's theorem, so perhaps that proof can be used here too. Since this function is a rational function, I will write this as $\frac{P(x, y)}{Q(x, y)}$, then the next step would be writing out the definition of the limit $\partial_x \partial_y f(a, b) = \lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\partial_y f(a + h, b) - \partial_y f(a, b)}{h}$... etc. etc. What is the next step here and is the proof for this statement the exact same as Clairaut's Theorem?

Comment: No need to reprove anything. Just check that rational functions satisfy the hypothesis of Clairaut's theorem, and then apply it.

Comment: See Schwartz's theorem about mixed partial derivatives.